org table: Easier formula syntax for multiple if-conditions?
Suppose a column in an org table needs to be filled with strings, depending on the numerical values of another column. Let's say "a" if the number is less than 2, and "b" otherwise. This could be done with if:
| 1 | a |
| 2 | b |
| 3 | b |
| 4 | b |
| 5 | b |
#+TBLFM: $2 = if($1 < 2, a, b)

My question: is there a compact way of doing this in case of multiple if-conditions? Suppose for instance we have

"a" if column ≤ 1
"b" if 1 < column ≤ 3
"c" if 3 < column ≤ 4
"d" otherwise

and note the non-uniform correspondence. I could implement this with nested ifs:
| 1 | a |
| 2 | b |
| 3 | b |
| 4 | c |
| 5 | d |
#+TBLFM: $2 = if($1 <= 1, a, if(1 < $1 <= 3, b, if(3 < $1 <= 4, c, d)))

But it becomes quite cumbersome with more character labels
Another possibility, I believe, is to use multiple #+TBLFM, but that would require calling each of them with C-c C-c.

You can use a cond in a lisp formula
| 1 | a |
| 2 | b |
| 3 | b |
| 4 | c |
| 5 | d |
#+TBLFM: $2='(cond((<= $1 1)'a) ((<= $1 3 )'b) ((<= $1 4)'c) (t 'd));N

An alternative is to use the pcase pattern-matching macro
| 1 | a |
| 2 | b |
| 3 | b |
| 4 | c |
| 5 | d |
#+TBLFM: $2='(pcase $1 ((pred (>= 1))'a) ((pred(>= 3))'b) ((pred( >= 4))'c) (_ 'd));N

Note that expanding the pcase macro results in a cond as in the first solution.

Fantastic, thank you! May I ask what is the final ;N for?

this forces $1 to be interpreted as a number. Otherwise, $1 is interpreted as a string.

Another solution would be to use the elisp 'pcase' function. For example, the formula would be $2='(pcase $1 ((pred (>= 1))'a) ((pred(>= 3))'b) ((pred( >= 4))'c) (_ 'd)));N . This could perhaps be relevant for more complex problems than the one proposed.

That's also a great solution, more compact, thank you! Great to have learned two important elisp functions as a bonus.

An even more compact form might be constructed by using this condp macro:
(require 'dash)
(defmacro condp (pred expr &rest clauses)
  `(cond
    ,@(-map (-lambda ((p1 p2))
              `((,pred ,expr ,p1) ,p2))
            (-partition 2 clauses))
    (:otherwise ,(when (cl-oddp (length clauses))
                   (-last-item clauses)))))

Which you would use thus:
#+TBLFM: $2='(condp <= $1 1 'a 3 'b 4 'c 'd);N

This expands to the same code as @gigiair's first example.
